# Eulerian paths visiting at most 2 vertices and odd degree edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, circles, eulerian-path

[image]

Hello,I am trying to understand Euler circle or not. If a graph has an euler path ,then it has at most 2  vertices with odd degree. (If I understand it right.)

I find some graphs I try solve them and ask you if my answers are right.

**On graph 1.**  it is Eulerian. We have u0,u1,u2,u3. We have 4 vertices. Each vertice has 2 edges max so it is Euler.

**On graph 2.**  u0,u1,u2,u3,u4. I have 5  vertices with 6 edges.
I have circle the u2 ,u1 on the image  (I have circle and u4 but wrong circle ,only u2 and u3 I wanted) .So, u2,u3 are vertices that have 3 edges. I wasn't sure if it is Euler or not.
Cause the most 2 vertiies with odd edges. Maybe it is Euler?

**On graph 3.** I have 20 vertices (If we count u0 until u19 is 20 vertices).Its not Euler cause
it has  all those  u1,u2,u3,u9,u14,u16,u17,u18  all those vertices have 3 edges each one that makes not Euler. u6 or u7 for example has 4 edges.Not Euler

**On graph 4.**It is u0 until u7 so it is 8 vertices.
u0,u1,u6,u7 are have odd degree (3 edges) so it is not euler .

**On graph 5.** the same it is not Euler example u0,u1,u2 are 3 vertices and have 3 edges each one .
Not euler

Comment: With the keyword [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path), or Eulerian circuit,  you will find a lot of information on the web.

Comment: @Jean Marie I am getting confused ...thats why I did solve those exercises to understand .

Comment: With other words I can't understand if it is Euler or not.

Comment: I just wanted to guide you on the exact names because you use for example "Euler circle" which is totally different mathematical object. But, sorry, I am not specialist of these questions.

Comment: my english aren't perfect ,sorry to hear that. But can you guide me to understand what to check so I will get when it is Euler or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, the first graph has an Euler circuit, and the third, fourth, and fifth all have more than two vertices of odd degree, so they have neither an Euler circuit nor an Euler path. The second graph is the interesting one. It has some vertices of odd degree, so it does not have an Euler circuit, but it has only two of them, so it does have an Euler path with those vertices as endpoints, for instance $u_2u_3u_0u_1u_4u_2u_1$. However, in order to be Eulerian, a graph must have an Euler circuit; an Euler path is not enough. Thus, only the first graph is Eulerian.

Comment: The way I  did - "solve" it  finds if it is Euler?

Comment: @maikler: If there are any vertices of odd degree, then it is not Eulerian. If all the vertices have even degree, it is Eulerian, provided that it is also connected.

Comment: If I get it right ,graph 1 :u0,u1,u2,u3 = 4 that it is even so Euler. graph 2: u0,u1,u2,u3,u4=5 so is odd it is not Euler. graph 3 : u19 so it 20 so it is Euler. Graph 4:u0,u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,u7=8 so it is Euler .That's how you mean?

Comment: @maikler: No, you should simply look for vertices of odd degree. There are none in the first graph, so it’s Eulerian. Each of the other graphs has at least one vertex of odd degree, so they are not Eulerian. (In fact, $u_1$ has odd degree in each of them.) That’s all that you need to do, though if you’re interested,tThe second graph has $2$ vertices of odd degree; the third has $14$; the fourth has $4$; and the fifth has $6$.

Comment: Sorry for my delay I am trying to understand it. So in my mind I should have that if an vertex has 3 edges(or degree) then it is not Euler circuit. So for graph 2 that it 2 vertex have 3 edges it's not a Euler circuit. Right?

Comment: @maikler: That’s right, but it’s not just degree $3$: if a graph has a vertex with $5$ edges, or $7$ edges, or any other odd number, then the graph is not Eulerian.

Comment: M.Scott yes I get I was talking for this case. I have got it .You are help me a lot man .I am greatful. It was a great help for me to understand it this.Thank you a lot

Comment: @maikler: You’re welcome; I’m glad that it helped.